# basic python what is wrong with this script

Tags: python-3.x

I am beginning to learn Python. I wrote this script but when I enter Kevin and 0, it show "Hello world" instead of "Kevin is great".

```
print ("hello world")
myName = input("what is your name?")
myVar = input("Enter a number: ")

if( myName == "Kevin"  and myVar == 0): 
   print ("Kevin is great!")
elif(myName == "Bob"):
   print("You are not great")
else:
   print("Hello world")
```

Comment: you need to convert `myVar` to `int` first. Or check for `myVar == '0'` instead of `myVar == 0`. Because `input()` returns a `str` (string) not an `int`

Comment: In my opinion, start with Python 2 first. Also, use raw_input instead of input for security reasons.

Comment: @Ambitions I wouldn't recommend python 2 to someone who is just starting to learn python. Python 2 will stop being supported soon so you would have to learn python 3 anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much @Farhan.K

Answer (score 0):

The input() function returns a string (in this case when you put 0 it will return "0") so you can parse it to a string with the int() function like this:

```
print ("hello world") 
myName = input("what is your name?") 
myVar = input("Enter a number: ")

myVar = int(myVar)
if (myName == "Kevin" and myVar == 0):
    print ("Kevin is great!") 
elif (myName == "Bob"): 
    print("You are not great") 
else: 
    print("Hello world")
```

For more information you can check the documentation:

[Input() Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

[Int() Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)

Answer (score 0):

Your second variable is going to prompt the user for a string not a integer. You will need to add either "int(" or "float(" before "input(" to change the string into an integer. For example:

`print ("hello world") 
myName = input("what is your name?")
myVar = int(input("Enter a number: ")) if( myName == "Kevin" and myVar == 0): print ("Kevin is great!") elif(myName == "Bob"): print("You are not great") else: print("Hello world") code here`